# Get label of json element with its id

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json

I have json elements in this form;

```
<rect style="fill: #888888; display: inline;" id="17" width="35.823246" height="35.823246" x="456.61066" y="65.9505" class="seatObj" label="A18"></rect>
```

How can I get the attribute `label` value?

Suppose `<rect .../>` tag a part of xml, then how can I get the same using C# console application?

Comment: You mean attribute `label="A18"` equals `id="17"`

Comment: It seems all but json.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementsById('17');
var label = elem.getAttribute('label');
alert(label);
```

Using jQuery:

```
alert($('#17').attr('label'));
```

You have 300 elements like this:

then try this:

```
$('rect').each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('label'));
});
```

here is the **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/v6LCm/1/)**

Another way of doing this by adding a **class** attribute into your **rect** element and select them by using that class.
I have added `class="sample"` **rect** element.
Check this **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6LCm/2/)**

```
 $('.sample').each(function(){
     alert($(this).attr('label'));
 });
```

Sample xml file.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <Test>
      <rect style="fill: #888888; display: inline;" id="17" width="35.823246" height="35.823246" x="456.61066" y="65.9505" class="seatObj" label="A18"></rect>
      <rect style="fill: #888888; display: inline;" id="18" width="35.823246" height="35.823246" x="456.61066" y="65.9505" class="seatObj" label="A19"></rect>
 </Test>
```

Parsing xml using c# console application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;

namespace Sample
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load("Url for Sample.xml");

            XmlNodeList elemList = doc.GetElementsByTagName("rect");
            for (int i = 0; i < elemList.Count; i++)
            {
                string attrVal = elemList[i].Attributes["label"].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(attrVal);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How can i write this with jquery?

Comment: `alert($('#17').attr('label'));`

Comment: If i want to write it in c# and think that file as xml, how can i parse it and get that labels?

Comment: @matewka said is true.. if you have invalid DOM attribute then try using attrutes with a prefix `data-`.

Comment: It is possible, let me try. c# console or mvc application?

Comment: c# console is possible

Comment: my last question is how can i add xml file to project? Where should i write it?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39805/discussion-between-bios-and-ebru-sezal)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `label` is **not a valid DOM attribute**. You need to change it to `data-label`. If you want to use any custom attributes you need to use them with `data-` prefix.
Also, `id` attribute's **first character must be a letter**, e.g. `a17`, not `17`.
If you consider the two above, then to acces this attribute you can do

```
$('#a17').attr('data-label')
```

or plain javascript

```
document.getElementById('a17').dataSet.label
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elem = $('#' + id)
alert(elem.attr("label"));
```